# Non-Metallic Surfaces are not receiving Roughness value

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

Its my first time using the Eevee render engine. I want to learn how to render some game ready 3d models in Eevee.

My issue is that if the surface has 0% metallic value it will have 100% roughness in blender.

This is my intended result from Marmoset Toolbag 3:
[image]

But this is the result I am getting in the LookDev mode in Blender 2.8:
[image]

This is my shader setup. Its pretty basic using the Principled BSDF:
[image]

And finally this is my export setting in Substance Painter:
[image]

I greatly appreciate any reply.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specularity is set to zero which means it will be a completely diffuse material. Adjusting that value should give you the desired look, unless there is something wrong with the textures.

Specularity set to zero:
[image]

Specularity set to one:
[image]

Comment: thnx, this seems to be the solution